# How did Nochka find weights in his proof of Cartan's conjecture?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Good evening,

I have just read Nochka's proof of Cartan's conjecture (Second Main Theorem of Nevanlinna Theory for linearly degenerate meromorphic curves in $\mathbb{CP}^n$). To prove the conjecture, Nochka introduced weights associated with the family of hyperplanes in N-subgeneral position. These weights are very complicated.

So I wonder how Nochka found these weights. Is there any intuitive explanation on these weights?

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks in advances,

Duc Anh